# Apple pay payment button in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, applepay

I have implemented Apple Pay with Target 8.4 and above versions.

When the device has ApplePay capability but it is not configured, we have to open Wallet app and initiates the process of adding cart.

When I implement the code for iOS 8.4, the PKPaymentButton is not displayed. 
It's working fine on iOS 9.0. Please check the below code for the same.

```
 if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]) {
//            Card configured

            self.btnApplePay = [self.btnApplePay initWithPaymentButtonType:PKPaymentButtonTypePlain paymentButtonStyle:PKPaymentButtonStyleBlack];
        }
        else {
//            Card not configured

            self.btnApplePay = [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:PKPaymentButtonTypeSetUp style:PKPaymentButtonStyleBlack];

        }
```

Also, find the attachment of screenshot.

[image: This is for iOS 8.4 version]

[image: This is For iOS 9.0 Version]

Please suggest, where I need to improve my code.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing on iOS 8.4? `PKPaymentButton` is only available on iOS 8.4 and up. iOS 8.3 and lower is not supported.

Comment: Yes I have selected iPhone 5 (8.4)

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different initialization methods. In the first one you are using

```
[self.btnApplePay initWithPaymentButtonType...
```

but in the second you are using

```
[PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:...
```

The second is a proper initialization, the first is not.